# Can we use static files without defining STATICFILES_DIRS in django

Tags: django

It's not nice to memorize a variable name to use a framework, is there another way that needs less of our memories?

Comment: You can just store all your static files in the app static folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` defines only *additional* directories that contains your static files. You don't have to specify it if you follow standard django directory pattern.

Keep app-related static files in 'static' directory of apps specified by the INSTALLED_APPS setting, for example `<project_root>\<app>\static\file.png`